# How to set sitewide download limits per user, to be reset each month.?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-memberships

I've got a WordPress membership site using WooCommerce and WooCommerce Membership plugins.

The site is used to download resources for schools. I need to set it so that a user can download a maximum of 150 products per month.

Any ideas?

I can set download limits per product but need to set it globally

Answer (score 0):

You must have a virtual product. Please review the following article for limit

https://orbisius.com/blog/set-download-limits-all-woocommerce-virtual-products-p4115